# Is it possible to detect keypresses using Google Tag Manager (GTM)?

Tags: google-tag-manager

The idea is to check if someone started filling in the form but hasn't submitted it. Is it possible to detect physical keypresses with GTM?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, quite easily, with the following:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" onkeyup="dataLayer.push({event:'textChanged', eventAction: this.value, eventLabel: location.href, eventValue: 0.0});">
```

Note that the eventAction, eventLabel and eventValue are optional and customizable.

GTM Tag: Google Analytics, "Event"

GTM trigger: Custom Event: "textChanged"

Answer (score 0):

GTM is Javascript, and in Javascript it is possible to detect key presses, so it is possible to detect key presses in GTM by using a custom HTML tag to implement your own keyup/keydown event handler. [Documentation for the event handler is here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keydown_event).

A more typical way to detect form interaction is to implement event handler for the change event on text fields. Warning, this might lead to excessive firing of events (but then, so might tracking keystrokes).